# how to javascript popup div close button working and div delete by javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I've come to with you for 2 help.

1) I've put a popup div into my HTML page by javascript. Here is the [website](http://abidhasan.zxq.net/firm/jobs.html). If you click the edit icon(at right side and center of the webpage), a popup box will be come. If you click the outside of that popup box, it will close. I put a close icon in the popup from. I want when anyone click on that close icon, the popup box will close too. I've put a javascript for that too. But, when I click the close icon, popup box will close, but a transparent background(div class="dimmer") will still stay unless clicking any side of the window. How can I solve this?

2) You see that there are two section of job details list. There are a remove icon also. I want that when I click the remove icon, the div beside that remove-icon will be deleted. How can I do that by javascript?

Necessary HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <header class="page_title">
            <h1>All Jobs</h1>
        </header>
        <article class="information">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Job ID</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>Deadline</th>
                        <th>Finish Date</th>
                        <th>Budget($)</th>
                        <th>Client ID</th>
                        <th>Bidder ID</th>
                        <th>Number of Supervisor</th>
                        <th>Name of Supervisor</th>
                        <th>Odesk Profile ID</th>
                        <th>Owner Type</th>
                        <th class="icon">

                            <a href="#"><img src="images/edit-icon.jpg" width="41" height="39" alt="Edit" title="Edit Job" class="icon_first" id="opener" /></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" width="41" height="39" alt="Delete" title="Delete Job" /></a>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>06/05/2013</td>
                        <td>11/05/2013</td>
                        <td>10/05/2013</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>John_01</td>
                        <td>abid</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>
                            1. Dolar
                            2. Soshi
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#">See the job at Odesk</a>                                    
                        </td>
                        <td>Member</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="lightbox">
                <section id="form">
                    <header class="titlebar">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/close-icon.png" width="33" height="32" alt="close" title="Close" id="closer" class="close" /></a>
                        <h1>Edit Form</h1>

                    </header>
                    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="#">
                        <label>Job ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="job_id" id="job_id" placeholder="1" />
                        <label>Start Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" placeholder="mm/dd/yy">
                        <label>Deadline:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="deadline" id="deadline">
                        <label>Finish Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="finish_date" id="finish_date">
                        <label>Budget($):</label>
                        <input type="number" name="Budget" id="Budget" placeholder="100">
                        <label>Client ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="client_id" id="client_id" placeholder="1" />
                        <label>Bidder ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="bidder_id" id="bidder_id" placeholder="1" />
                        <label>Number of Supervisor:</label>
                        <select title="Supervisor">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Odesk Profile ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="odesk_id" id="odesk_id" placeholder="https://www.odesk.com/jobs/Frontend-engineer">
                        <label>Owner Type:</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="owner_type" id="owner_type" value="member" /><label class="text_label">Member</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="owner_type" id="owner_type" value="employee" /><label class="text_label">Employee</label>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </section>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="information">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Job ID</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>Deadline</th>
                        <th>Finish Date</th>
                        <th>Budget($)</th>
                        <th>Client ID</th>
                        <th>Bidder ID</th>
                        <th>Number of Supervisor</th>
                        <th>Name of Supervisor</th>
                        <th>Odesk Profile ID</th>
                        <th>Owner Type</th>
                        <th class="icon">

                            <a href="#"><img src="images/edit-icon.jpg" width="41" height="39" alt="Edit" title="Edit Job" class="icon_first" /></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" width="41" height="39" alt="Delete" title="Delete Job" /></a>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>06/05/2013</td>
                        <td>11/05/2013</td>
                        <td>10/05/2013</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>John_01</td>
                        <td>abid</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>
                            1. Dolar

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#">See the job at Odesk</a>                                    
                        </td>
                        <td>Member</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </article>
    </div>
```

Necessary CSS code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clear { clear: both; }
/*html5 display rule*/
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 26px;    
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

header.page_title {
    background: #F2F2F0;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0; 
}
#form {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 2px;   
}
#form label { 
    display: block; 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 200px; 
    float:left; 
    margin: 5px 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 15px; 
}
#form label.text_label {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px 20px 15px 10px; 
}
#form input, #form select {
    float:left; 
    font-size:13px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
#form input[type=text], #form input[type=date], #form input[type=number], #form input[type=email] { 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 27px; 
}
#form select {
    width: 500px;
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#form input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;  
}
#form textarea { 
    float: left; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 82px; 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 13px; 
}
#form input[type="submit"] { 
    margin: 10px 0 20px 220px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 30px; 
    background: #00AEEC; 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(38, 151, 72, 0.5), 0 1px 0 #9FE662 inset; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#form input[type="submit"]:hover { 
    background: #33BEF0;
}

article.information {
    position: relative; 
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    float: left;
}
.table { 
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    margin: 25px 0 0 0; 
    width: 700px; 
    text-align: center; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    float: left;
}
.table th { 
    font-size: 13px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    border-right: 1px solid #EDEDEB; 
    border-left: 1px solid #EDEDEB; 
    color: #042D40; 
    background: #F2F2F0;
}
.table td { 
    padding: 10px 5px; 
    border-right: 1px solid #EDEDEB; 
    border-left: 1px solid #EDEDEB; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDEB; 
    color: #669; 
}
.table a { 
    color: #669; 
}
.table a:hover { 
    color: #009; 
}
.icon {
    float: right;
    width: 130px;
}
.table th.icon {
    clear: both;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

.icon img {
    float: left;    
}
.icon_first {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;  
}

#lightbox{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    border-radius: 11px 11px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    color: #333;
    z-index:100;
    width: 800px;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
}

.dimmer{
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .5;
    top: 0;
    z-index:99;
}
#lightbox .titlebar {
    background-color: #00AEEC;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #00AEEC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 17px 20px 13px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -3px;
    width: 95.2%;   
}
#lightbox .close {
    float: right;
    margin: -10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
var opener = document.getElementById("opener");
var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");


opener.onclick = function(){

    var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox"),
        dimmer = document.createElement("div");

    dimmer.style.width =  window.innerWidth + 'px';
    dimmer.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    dimmer.className = 'dimmer';

    dimmer.onclick = function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this);   
        lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    document.body.appendChild(dimmer);

    lightbox.style.visibility = 'visible';

    return false;
}


var closer = document.getElementById("closer");
closer.onclick = function closepopup()
{
  lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dynamicly add the black div inside the body. Your code delete it when you click on it, but when you click on "closer", you dont delete it.

Add this on the closer click :

```
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('dimmer')[0]);
```

2) For your delete thing, You need to add this code :

```
var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');
for(var i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {
    var btn = deleteBtn[i];
    btn.onclick = function() {
        for (var k=0; k < deleteBtn.length; k++){
            if(this == deleteBtn[k]){
                break;
            }
        }


        var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
        var target = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('article');
        wrapper.removeChild(target[k])

        deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');
    }
}
```

It will search the index of the clicked button and delete the respective article.

Comment: 1)Thanks! It's working!

2) For deleting div, you may not understand my condition. I didn't mean to delete the popup div by clicking close icon on popup div. I want to delete/remove the div (<article class="information">..</article>) completely when anyone click the delete icon(not the close icon on popup div) beside the edit icon.

Comment: But, unfortunately, 2) is still not working :(

http://abidhasan.zxq.net/firm/jobs.html

Comment: Ok i examined you code and here's what's wrong. 1)Your btn deleter should be an id, but a class (id are for unique element). 2) The code shouldnt be in a click function. you loop throud your btn and set even in the loop. 3) the 'yourClass' should be the class of your btn, not your article. If you do those 3 things, it should work.

Comment: I've updated again, but still it's not working. Can you please, write for last time the exact set of codes? Thanks again

Comment: Ok the code is working (I tested it) and the only change remaining is to add the class 'delete' to the `<a>` containing the 'x' image.

Comment: Yes, I added it before you telling. But, it isn't working. See the Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/PJLzkyJ.jpg

Comment: Just realized that you have 2 div wrapper. Just change `var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];` to `var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[1];` or add an id to your second wrapper and write `var wrapper = document.getElementById('yourNewId');`

Comment: Hi, I've done it too now, but still no change. You can see the new update page: http://abidhasan.zxq.net/firm/job.html

Comment: `getElementById` dont need an 's' at 'element' (it is unique) THEN if everything go right, it should work!

Comment: Thanks, it's working! http://abidhasan.zxq.net/firm/test.html

Can you help me again for another section? You remembered that besides deleteBtn icon, there was a Edit Icon. If anyone, click at that, a popup window(div id="lightbox") would be come. For becoming id, it worked only for first edit icon. So, I changed that div into class, so it's not working anymore. Because javascript for getelementById and getElementsByClassName isn't same. As I ain't skilled at javascript, so I can't write a javascript newly.

Comment: My previous script for that popup section is:
<code>
var opener = document.getElementById("opener");
var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
opener.onclick = function(){
  var lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox"),
  dimmer = document.createElement("div");
  dimmer.style.width =  window.innerWidth + 'px';
  dimmer.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  dimmer.className = 'dimmer';
  dimmer.onclick = function(){
     document.body.removeChild(this);   
     lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
</code>

Comment: > document.body.appendChild(dimmer);
>  lightbox.style.visibility = 'visible';
>  return false;
> }

var closer = document.getElementById("closer");
closer.onclick = function closepopup()
{
  lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('dimmer')[0]);
  
}

Comment: Thanks, it's working.
http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/r5bEU/1/
 But, I also try to follow your code for the close icon at popup window, but, it doesn't work. Will you please, tell me the code for that. I've written that code:

for(var a=0; a<document.getElementsByClassName('close').length; a++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('close')[a].onclick = function(){
        //Previous Code  
        lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   document.body.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('dimmer')[0]);
    }
}

Comment: You didnt get the lightbox element, i just add this line befor your code : `var lightbox = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r5bEU/2/